# which parser is most suitable for [biomedical] relation extraction?

Tags: parsing, nlp, information-extraction

I have read about continuency parser and dependency parser. but confused which could be the best choice.

my task is to extract relationship from english wikipedia text(other source may also be included later). What I need is an semantic path(with only most important information) between the two entities interesting. for instance,

form text:
***"In America, diabetes is, as everybody knows, a common disease."***

I need the information: 
**"diabetes is disease"**

which implementation of parser would you suggest? Stanford? Maltparser? or other?

any clue is appreciated.

Comment: here http://videolectures.net/ecmlpkdd09_reichartz_dtkrenlt/ is something related...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean a syntactic parser vs a dependency parser? The [online Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) shows you how these parses are different.

Syntactic Parse

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (PP (IN In)
      (NP (NNP America)))
    (, ,)
    (NP (NNP diabetes))
    (VP (VBZ is) (, ,)
      (PP (IN as)
        (NP (NN everybody) (NNS knows)))
      (, ,)
      (NP (DT a) (JJ common) (NN disease)))))
```

Dependency Parse (collapsed)

```
prep_in(disease-13, America-2)
nsubj(disease-13, diabetes-4)
cop(disease-13, is-5)
nn(knows-9, everybody-8)
prep_as(disease-13, knows-9)
det(disease-13, a-11)
amod(disease-13, common-12)
root(ROOT-0, disease-13)
```

They are not that different actually (see Collins' thesis or Nieve's book for more details) but I find dependency parses easier to work with. As you can see, you get a direct relation for diabetes -> disease. Then you can attach the copula.

Comment: For biomedical relations, GENIA parser might be useful, but it depends what sort of relations are used. Go read the literature, I would suggest the BioNLP competitions in recent years.

Comment: oh thanks a lot for your info, let me read the things you mentioned. so, you also think dependency parser is more suitable in this case, right?   another reason I prefer dependency parser is speed. continuency parser seems to be a lot slower.

Comment: I think the relations returned by a dependency parser are easier to work with, vs building some tree object and trying to relate the nodes to each other. Saves some time mostly.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, a dependency parser like the Stanford dependency parser would be the right choice for you. I would recommend using the [BLLIP reranking parser](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser) with [David McClosky's biomedical model](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~mcclosky/biomedical.html) for getting the phrase structure and then converting to dependencies with [Stanford Dependencies](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml). This way you would get better dependency trees/graphs for biomedical text.